# React Native get view height

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Green**: full screen view
**Red**: is a view style absolute bottom:0
**Blue**: is a view style absolute height:‘100%’

**WHAT I WANT**
I want find the way to get height of Red View (height isn’t determined).
This height I want to use it for marginBottom for Blue View.

[EXPO SNACK](https://snack.expo.dev/@stefanosalexandrou/exampler)

```
<View style={{
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  flex:1
}}>

<View style={{
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  position:'absolute',
  height:'100%',
  left:0,
  right:0,
  top:0,
  marginBottom: HEIGHT_OF_RED_VIEW
}}>
</View>

<View style={{
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  position:'absolute',
  left:0,
  right:0,
  bottom:0,
  padding:20
}}>
<Text>Lorem Ipsum</Text>
</View>

</View>
```

[image]

Comment: Why is your blue absolute, without that you wouldn't have this problem? This is not the proper way to do things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try onLayout method of view it will call once the rendeing of your view is completed take a look at example below

```
<View
      onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => {
         const { x, y, width, height } = nativeEvent.layout
            setHeight(height)
      }}
</View>
```

you can have height variable defined in your state, and you can use that variable for allocating the margin bottom

You can try code below I have made changes in your expo slack

```
import { Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {useState} from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState('')
  return (
    <View style={{
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        flex: 1
    }}>

        <View style={{
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            position: 'absolute',
            // height: '100%',
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            bottom: height,// here is you want to have some addintional spacing try adding some value in you hight (ex. height+20)
        }}>
        </View>

        <View
            onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => {
                const { x, y, width, height } = nativeEvent.layout
                setHeight(height)
            }}
            style={{
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                position: 'absolute',
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                padding: 20
            }}>
            <Text>Lorem Ipsum</Text>
        </View>

    </View>
);
}
```

Comment: The height is not defined is 'auto' if is defined I know the way. Because I don't understand how to use this can check code in expo snack.

Comment: check your attached EXPO SNAK I have updated your code.

Note:- you do not have to provide height if you are allocating position as absolute and adding that view inside a view which will have flex:1 it will take whole height of view

Comment: Thanks you very much. *any idea for the error "JSON value "of type NSString cannot be converted to a ABI46_0_0YGValue. Did you forget the % or pt suffix?

Comment: No idea please describe the details with another question